# Acetone resistant elastomer

Tags: polymers

I am in search of an elastomer that can be dissolved in solution and applied and cured at room temperature, but that has good chemical stability to acetone once cured. Does any such elastomer exist?

Answer (score 1):

From this chart at [Mykin](https://mykin.com/rubber-chemical-resistance-chart), [EPDM](https://www.applerubber.com/blog/epdm-basics-chemical-compatibility-and-important-benefits-you-need-to-know/), [Butyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyl_rubber) and [Kalrez](https://sealution.eu/materials/ffkm-kalrez-2/) (FFKM, a Viton derivative) are marked compatible with acetone.

As for applying in a solvent:

- [EPDM dissolves in toluene and trichloroethylene](https://www.applerubber.com/blog/epdm-basics-chemical-compatibility-and-important-benefits-you-need-to-know/), but it is not stated if the polymer is usable after evaporation.
- Butyl rubber can be dissolved in [hexane](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3046244A/en) and other solvents, and is sold as [liquid butyl rubber](https://www.epdmcoatings.com/butyl-liquid-rubber-one-gallon.php).
- [Viton-based adhesives](https://reglinrubber.com.au/products/adhesives-and-sealants/tha-3000-viton-adhesive/) are available.

However, you'd need to research if any of these are suitable in *your specific application*, and if any are cost-effective.